# HERE WeGo access to running application information

Tags: android, here-api

Is there a way to programmatically request current status information (location, tta, speed) from an active instance of the HERE WeGo app?  I know I can use an alternate method for location but would like to access TTA and possibly additional current status information from a running GPS program without requiring the user to input data. Example: Current time, location, speed, ETA(TTA), logged with the click of a button or voice command.  I would specifically like to be able to use HERE because of its off-line capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. It would violate the user's privacy and allow an unsuspecting application to track the user :)

Comment: Thanks for responding David but if the mapping program is started by the requesting app with permissions, this would not be a privacy issue.  Apps, with permission can access current location. time is not a problem and speed can be calculated with multiple location requests.  I have found ways to use Google Maps and HERE online to get the ETA information I but want to accomplish this off line (HERE has a sort of local access for an annual fee well beyond the monetary scope of the app and requiring a separate map download).